# Backup stored procedure only copies one table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I´ve been trying to create a stored procedure that will copy my database to another database. The problem is that only the first table is copying. Do you guys see any errors in the code?

```
     DELIMITER $$

     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fes_backup  $$

     CREATE PROCEDURE  do_backup (IN name_bbdd VARCHAR(20), IN new_name_bbdd VARCHAR(20))
     BEGIN

        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE name_table VARCHAR(20);

        DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema=name_bbdd AND table_type="base table";

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

        OPEN cur1;

        bucle: LOOP

           FETCH cur1 INTO name_table;
           IF done=1 THEN
              LEAVE bucle;
           END IF;

           SELECT CONCAT("Copio ",name_table," a nova base de dades ",new_name_bbdd);

           SET @aux = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE ",name_table," LIKE ", name_bbdd, ".", name_table);
           PREPARE stmt1 FROM @aux;
           EXECUTE stmt1;
           DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

           SET @aux = CONCAT("INSERT INTO ",name_table," SELECT * FROM ", name_bbdd, ".", name_table);
           PREPARE stmt1 FROM @aux;
           EXECUTE stmt1;
           DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

        END LOOP bucle;

        CLOSE cur1;

     END$$

     DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about using a local variable `aux` instead of the user variable `@aux`?

Comment: Doesn´t seem to make any difference, but thanks for answering!